# I need to Add my already-installed-Pycharm to my Anaconda software

Tags: pycharm, anaconda, anaconda3

I already had PyCharm Community Edition installed when I installed Anaconda yesterday. I want to access PyCharm from Anaconda Environment directly but all I see is PyCharm install button on there. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

so if you have the base community edition of Anaconda Navigator the version of PyCharm that is originally being referenced is PyCharm Professional Edition. If you have the Community Edition installed then it will show up as well as a separate entry. If you have PyCharm installed and running you can change the environment and point it to Anaconda.
Here is the link to the official documentation if further clarification is needed: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/pycharm/